# Excel conditional formatting always relative?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm creating a little project management spreadsheet for myself in Excel 2013. It looks like:

[image: screenshot of Excel showing columns, some of which have conditional formatting]

Notice that the columns on the left use the Data Bar Conditional Formatting, but don't look quite right. Here is what that group looks like in the formatting wizard:

[image: Edit Formatting rule screen]

Even though the max is set to 100%, it looks like they auto-scale based on their largest member, and they use some strange logarithmic algorithm to determine bar length. In other words, if I changed the 18% to 90%, the top bar will shrink and the new highest will have the longest bar.

How do I get them to scale linearly to 100% instead of relatively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using percentages in the cells try changing

```
Minimum: Number = 0
Maximum: Number = 1
```

This represents the bars relative to minimum 0% and maximum 100%